# Size and position of TabTip.exe (virtual keyboard) on Windows 10?

Tags: delphi, winapi, virtual-keyboard

Need to determine the size (width, height) and position (left, top) of TabTip.exe (virtual keyboard) on windows 10?

The task is to move the panel, on which all the components are located, so that the input field to which the input focus was transferred was above the virtual keyboard.

Working with Windows 10 is not under the admin, but the compiled project is run as administrator!

The following solutions work in Windows 7,Windows 8, in Windows 10 they do not work:

```
uses ..., Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Dwmapi
...
procedure TForm1.SizeKeyboard;
var KeyBoardRect: TRect;
    KeyboardWindow : HWND;
begin
  KeyboardWindow := FindWindow('IPTip_Main_Window', nil);
  if (KeyboardWindow <> 0) then
    KeyBoardRect := GetRect1(KeyboardWindow);
  ...
end;
...

function TForm1.GetRect1(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var KeyBoardRect: Trect;
begin
    GetWindowRect(AKeyboardWindow, KeyBoardRect);
    Result := KeyBoardRect;
end;


function TForm1.GetRect2(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var KeyBoardRect: Trect;
begin
    DwmGetWindowAttribute(AKeyboardWindow, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS,     @KeyBoardRect, sizeof(KeyBoardRect));

    Result :=  KeyBoardRect;
end;
```

but

The Windows 10 touch keyboard is a UWP application. UWP applications do not have native windows, and can not be referenced through HWNDs. You can use UI Automation to get the bounding rectangle of the touch keyboard [Get size of Windows 10 touch keyboard window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509973/get-size-of-windows-10-touch-keyboard-window)!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671425(v=vs.85).aspx!

Loaded type library - UIAutomationClient interfaces IUIAutomation, IUIAutomationElement (UIAutomationClient_TLB)

```
function TForm1.getRect4(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var AUTOMATION : IUIAutomation;
  Root : IUIAutomationElement;
  rRect:UIAutomationClient_TLB.tagRECT;
begin
    AUTOMATION := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
    AUTOMATION.GetRootElement(Root);
    AUTOMATION.ElementFromHandle(Pointer(AKeyboardWindow), Root);
    Root.Get_CurrentBoundingRectangle(rRect);
    Result :=  TRect(rRect);
end;

function TForm1.getRect5(AKeyboardWindow : HWND): Trect;
var AUTOMATION : IUIAutomation;
  Root : IUIAutomationElement;
  olRect: OleVariant;
  rRect:UIAutomationClient_TLB.tagRECT;
begin
  AUTOMATION := CoCUIAutomation.Create;
  AUTOMATION.GetRootElement(Root);
  AUTOMATION.ElementFromHandle(Pointer(AKeyboardWindow), Root);
  Root.GetCurrentPropertyValue(BoundingRectangle, olRect);
  AUTOMATION.VariantToRect(olRect, rRect);

  Result :=  TRect(rRect);
end;
```

keypad call

```
function ExpandEnvironmentVar(var Value: string): Boolean;
var
  R: Integer;
  Expanded: string;

procedure StrResetLength(var S: string);
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    for I := 0 to Length(S) - 1 do
      if S[I + 1] = #0 then
      begin
        SetLength(S, I);
        Exit;
      end;
  end;

begin
  SetLength(Expanded, 1);
  R := ExpandEnvironmentStrings(PChar(Value), PChar(Expanded), 0);
  SetLength(Expanded, R);
  Result := ExpandEnvironmentStrings(PChar(Value), PChar(Expanded), R) <> 0;
  if Result then
  begin
    StrResetLength(Expanded);
    Value := Expanded;
  end;
end;



procedure TForm1.btnCloseClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyHandle1: THandle;
begin
  MyHandle1 := FindWindow('IPTip_Main_Window', nil);
  if MyHandle1 <> 0 then
    PostMessage(MyHandle1, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
end;



procedure TForm1.btnOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  btnClose.Click;
  S := '%CommonProgramW6432%\microsoft shared\ink\tabtip.exe';
  ExpandEnvironmentVar(S);
  ShellExecute(0, PChar('open'), PChar(S), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Nothing succeeded(left = 0 top = 0 width = 0 height = 0)! Has anyone done something like this, or does he know what to do?

Comment: What does "nothing succeeded" mean?

Comment: result of functions 
 GetCurrentPropertyValue
 Get_CurrentBoundingRectangle

left = 0 
top = 0
width = 0 
height = 0

Comment: Please provide details in the question rather than comments

Comment: %CommonProgramW6432% is not something you should be using. The class name of the keyboard window is an internal implementation detail.

Comment: Don't use the %CommonProgramW6432% why not? 
TbTip.exe - haven't Window Text (GetWindowText). 
I think it's related to UWP applications

Comment: CommonProgramW6432 does not exist on a 32-bit system.

Comment: I've gone part-way to solving this in this unit: https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/2098ebafd20aa43f6c5a69503b06c4ca. As per my comment, I'm guessing I've messed up a declaration or something. Feel free to play with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement [`IFrameworkInputPaneHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Enables an app to be notified when the input pane (the on-screen keyboard or handwriting panel) is being shown or hidden. This allows the app window to adjust its display so that no input areas (such as a text box) are obscured by the input pane.

See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150608-00/?p=45431/) for details and example code.